# How can I get id_token of gcloud using java instead of gcloud command

Tags: java, authentication, token, gcloud

Can someone give me a piece of java code to get id_token on GCP using google account?

I've got a restful api endpoint service deployed on GCP to test. I can use my google account to get the id_token using command "gcloud config config-helper"(e.g. id_token: eyJadhI6....). This id_token is then placed in the header as the value of authorization. The REST request is fired as expected. But I need to do the same using Java instead of from console command line to get a valid id_token.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/ check here

Comment: Hi dev2d, could you be speicific? I'm new to GCP, not sure which reference is the one. A concrete piece of code would be perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use one of the Google-provided client libraries (SDKs).

These are open-sourced and tested by Google and provide you with a much better platform for your development.

See:
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java

and:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java#authentication

Using these SDKs you will avoid the complexity in navigating your way through the underlying REST APIs directly.

Couple of useful tricks|pointers:

- [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) enables you to use the REST APIs from the browser
- If you append `--log-http` to *any* `gcloud` command, the REST calls are logged.

**NB** There are 2 flavors of APIs (API Client Libraries and Cloud Client Libraries) see [explanation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained). The Cloud Client Libraries are more modern, are idiomatic and are preferred **if** you're mostly using GCP.

HTH!